# How to override file_public_path in install profile?

Tags: distributions

I want to create an install profile that creates the files folder in the document root, www.example.com/files, and not the sites/default folder.

I have tried two methods of doing this and both partially works, they create the folder in the correct place, but when the site is finished installing the admin/config/media/file-system is showing "sites/default/files".

**Method 1 used:**

Added "$conf['file_public_path'] = "files";" to settings.php

Note: This line was actually removed from settings.php after installation finished

**Method 2:**

added the below code to [myprofile].profile:

```
function sitebase_install_tasks_alter(&$tasks, &$install_state) {
  $GLOBALS['conf']['file_public_path'] = 'files';
}
```

In both cases the **Verify requirements** step was testing for "files".

How come Drupal all of a sudden seems to lose this setting and instead inserting the wrong value in the db? Do I need to also manually insert this in the db in [myprofile].install?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to look at this very recent blog post from [PreviousNext: Collecting and writing configuration settings to setting.php from an install profile](http://previousnext.com.au/blog/collecting-and-writing-configuration-settings-settingphp-install-profile) for answers to this question and your other about creating your own step in an install profile.

From that blog post regarding their install profiles form submit handler:

> Then we had to do the actual storing of these variables. Now at this
>   stage the database connection is not setup so you cannot call
>   [variable_set()](http://api.drupal.org/variable_set), you have to use another of Drupal's lesser known api
>   functions - [drupal_rewrite_settings()](http://api.drupal.org/drupal_rewrite_settings). This is the function Drupal
>   uses to write the $databases variable to your settings.php. But with
>   some minor wrangling you can use it to also write $conf variables to
>   settings.php, which are from that point forward available for use via
>   [variable_get()](http://api.drupal.org/variable_get). And therefore available for us to use to define our
>   connection settings for the solr server. Because
>   drupal_rewrite_settings should only be called once (to avoid having
>   your settings overridden) we had to duplicate what the standard
>   install does - ie writing the database settings - then we could write
>   our own $conf settings.